# Call Javascript function after submit a form and refresh page

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have an onepage website with a form that submits user data by mail using PHP. When the user click on Submit, I need to open an overlay that contains a success message. The problem is that, when the form is submitted and the page refreshed, my overlay automatically desappear and the user does not have the necessary time to close it by himself. Could you help me with this topic?

Thank you!

Here is my form:

```
    <form id="contact-us" method="post" action="#" >
    <div class="col-xs-6 wow animated slideInLeft" data-wow-delay=".5s">
    <!-- Name -->
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required class="form" placeholder="Nombre" />
    <!-- Email -->
    <input type="email" name="mail" id="mail" required class="form" placeholder="E-mail" />
    <!-- Subject -->
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" required class="form" placeholder="Asunto" />
    </div><!-- End Left Inputs -->
    <!-- Right Inputs -->
    <div class="col-xs-6 wow animated slideInRight" data-wow-delay=".5s">
    <!-- Message -->
    <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form textarea" required placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
    </div><!-- End Right Inputs -->
    <!-- Bottom Submit -->
    <div class="relative fullwidth col-xs-12">
    <!-- Send Button -->
    <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="form-btn semibold" onclick="openNav14()">Enviar</button>
    </div><!-- End Bottom Submit -->
    <!-- Clear -->
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
```

Here are my functions:

```
function openNav14() {
document.getElementById("myNav14").style.width = "100%";

}

/* Close when someone clicks on the "x" symbol inside the overlay */
function closeNav14() {
document.getElementById("myNav14").style.width = "0%";
}
```

Comment: When you refresh a page the page returns to its original state unless of course you have cookies, or session variables that you keep track of. Since you don't show it in your code I couldn't say for sure, but I imagine that your myNav14 has a width that is 0% when you navigate to the page. If that is the case of course refreshing the page would make your myNav14 "close". Are you sure that you want to refresh your page?

Comment: Since (if?) this is a single-page application you can catch the form submit and submit it through AJAX instead. That way the page does not get refreshed at all -- you get the result of the submit in your ajax callback and do something to remove the overlay and possibly add a status message.